# How to add canonical URL in Nuxt3?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'd like to add the canonical URL to each page in my Nuxt3 application.

In Nuxt2 one would do:

```js
// ~/layouts/default.vue 

export default {
  head() {
    return {
      link: [
        {
          rel: 'canonical',
          href: 'https://example.com' + this.$route.path
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In Nuxt3 I tried to use:

```js
// ~/layouts/default.vue 

<script setup>
const route = useRoute()
useHead({
  link: [
    {
      rel: 'canonical',
      href: 'https://example.com' + route.path,
    },
  ],
})
</script>
```

However, this is not updated when navigating. How to make this reactive?

Comment: Tried to add a `return` on the second one too?

Comment: Not sure, what to `return` where. https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-head#examples

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Argument has to be turned into a function:

```html
// ~/layouts/default.vue 

<script setup>
const route = useRoute()
useHead(() => ({
  link: [
    {
      rel: 'canonical',
      href: 'https://example.com' + route.path,
    },
  ],
}))
</script>
```

Comment: I change my mind. They might make an update, and it should work and no need to be in life cycle hook. XD

Comment: As you can see, here you added a return (with your arrow function). Like in the initial snippet of code (return between `head` and `link`).

Comment: it's better to put it in app.vue instead in order to apply in all layouts of the project

Answer (score 0):

@kissu answer is right but i want to add a way to dynamically get baseUrl, if you are not using ssg you can do this:

```
//in your composables

export const useAbsoluteUrl=()=>{
  const url = useRequestURL();
  const getAbsoluteUrl=(path)=>{
    const baseUrl=url.protocol+'//'+ url.host
    return baseUrl+path
  };
  return {getAbsoluteUrl}
}

//in app.vue to effect all layouts
const {getAbsoluteUrl}=useAbsoluteUrl();
useHead({
  link: [
    {
      rel: 'canonical',
      href: getAbsoluteUrl(route.path),
    },
  ]
});
```